# Iterate the list

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I want to create a `Map` in which `EntryDate__c` should be the Key and rest other data like `ProjectName__c`, `TaskName__c` and `TimeDuration__c`. I want to store in the `List` but the important thing is that I want a single entry for a particular date.

```
0: {Id: "a007F00001JiVo9QAF", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-24", ProjectName__c: "Project2", TaskName__c: "Task2", TimeDuration__c: 4}

1: {Id: "a007F00001JiVTzQAN", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-24", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 5.25}

2: {Id: "a007F00001JhJVqQAN", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-17", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task2", TimeDuration__c: 1}

3: {Id: "a007F00001JhLylQAF", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-17", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 0.83}

4: {Id: "a007F00001JhJGqQAN", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-17", P
rojectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 7}

5: {Id: "a007F00001Jh5zvQAB", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-16", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task3", TimeDuration__c: 1.75}

6: {Id: "a007F00001Jh5zgQAB", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-16", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task2", TimeDuration__c: 3.75}

7: {Id: "a007F00001Jh5zWQAR", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-16", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 2}

8: {Id: "a007F00001Jh5zRQAR", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-15", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 2}

9: {Id: "a007F00001Jh6UNQAZ", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-12", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 6}

10: {Id: "a007F00001Jh6USQAZ", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-12", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task2", TimeDuration__c: 2.25}

11: {Id: "a007F00001JhXu4QAF", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-05", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task2", TimeDuration__c: 4}

12: {Id: "a007F00001JhWqFQAV", EntryDate__c: "2018-10-02", ProjectName__c: "Project1", TaskName__c: "Task1", TimeDuration__c: 9}
length: 13
```

the Map structure should be like this

```
"2018-10-24"    Project2,Task2,4, Project1, Task1,5.25

"2018-10-17"    Project1, Task2,1, Project1, Task1,0.83, Project1, Task2,7,
```

Please help me to get the map structure like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say, this custom object is called Entry__c . In order to have one one entry per `EntryDate__c` you need to create new wrapper class `EntryWrapper`.

```
public EntryWrapper{
    public String projectName {get; set;}
    public String taskName {get; set;}
    public Decimal timeDuration {get; set;}

    public EntryWrapper(Entry__c entry){
        projectName = entry.ProjectName__c;
        taskName = entry.TaskName__c;
        timeDuration = entry.TimeDuration__c;
    }

    public override String toString(){
        return projectName + ', ' + taskName + ',' + String.valueOf(timeDuration);
    }
}
```

Here override `toString` method to get output in desired way.

```
List<Entry__c> entries = new List<Entry__c>();
Map<Date, List<EntryWrapper>> entriesWrapperByEntryDate = new Map<Date, List<EntryWrapper>>();

for(Entry__c entry :entries){
    List<EntryWrapper> entryWrappers = null;
    if(entriesWrapperByEntryDate.containsKey(entry.EntryDate__c)){
        entryWrappers = entriesWrapperByEntryDate.get(entry.EntryDate__c);
    }else{
        entryWrappers = new List<EntryWrapper>();
    }
    entryWrappers.add(
        new EntryWrapper(entry)
        );
    entriesWrapperByEntryDate.put(entry.EntryDate__c, entryWrappers);
}

System.debug(entriesWrapperByEntryDate); // result will be in desired output way
```

Comment: Thank you  very much Oleksandr Berehovskiy . It's working for me.

Comment: Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me that the `toString` override is a requirement, so if not this simpler approach without a wrapper class makes sense:

```
List<Entry__c> entries = ...

Map<Date, List<Entry__c>> byDate = new Map<Date, List<Entry__c>>();

for (Entry__c e : entries) {
    List<Entry__c> forDate = byDate.get(e.EntryDate__c);
    if (forDate == null) {
        forDate = new List<Entry__c>();
        byDate.put(e.EntryDate__c);
    }
    forDate(e);
}
System.debug(JSON.stringify(byDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of wrapper. You can simply iterate over the list.

```
List<Entry__c> entries = new List<Entry__c>();
Map<Date, List<String>> entriesByEntryDate = new Map<Date, List<String>>();
For(EntryDate__c eachRecord : entries){
    if(entriesByEntryDate.containskey(eachRecord.EntryDate__c)){
      List<String> entriesList = new List<String>();
      entriesList = entriesByEntryDate.get(eachRecord.EntryDate__c);
      entriesList.add(eachRecord.ProjectName__c+eachRecord.TaskName__c+String.valueOf(eachRecord.TimeDuration__c));
      entriesByEntryDate.put(eachRecord.EntryDate__c, entriesList);
    }
    else{
     entriesByEntryDate.put(eachRecord.EntryDate__c, new List<String>{eachRecord.ProjectName__c+eachRecord.TaskName__c+String.valueOf(eachRecord.TimeDuration__c)});
    }
}
```

Check this out.